# How to deploy ASP Core Web API VueJS site to IIS

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am new to VueJS and SPAs in general.  I have created a new ASP Core site with a WebAPI controller for data and a VueJS front end.  I am now trying to deploy this site to IIS and I am not sure how to do it correctly.  I created a new application in IIS with an application pool set to "no-managed-code" and set the physical location to the VueJS app /dist folder.  The site is loading, but I'm getting 404's for all of my service calls.  I assume this is because the root of the site is set to the VueJS app folder instead of the root of the ASP Core folder.  How do I set this up correctly to serve my app from myServer/mySite and also have my service endpoints as myServer/mySite/api/myController/myAction?

Comment: The simplest way is to have your app and api on different sites like app.example.com and api.example.com. In axios you can set a base url for your api calls so it knows where your api is. dotnet also has Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions package that can add middleware to serve the Vue js files.

Comment: to deploy vue js app in iis you need to run this command: `npm run build` .If building is successful, you can find the folder with the name “dist”.use this folder as site path in iis. eg: C:\vueapp\dist

Comment: @Rosco Thanks, I had thought about that but I am hopeful there's another way.  This just doesn't seem like the correct approach.  Though, if I don't figure it out, this will just have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scenario: Your dotnet core app has the API endpoints and you want to host the client site SPA on the same site. API calls will go through to the dotnet app and any other request will serve the index.html of the SPA.

.NET core supports this scenario with the methods from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` namespace like `UseSpa()`

Also note that in .NET 5 these extensions are moving to separate package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`. It is available now but not well documented.

Your build SPA should go in `ClientApp/dist` in this example

e.g.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices;

public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // In production, the SPA files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();

        // Must be near the end of the method because 
        // it will send any unhandled requests to index.html for SPA
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // Development requests are send through to local node server
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8080/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```